# ATTiny817 XPlained mini enabling interrupts

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt-handling, atmel, attiny

I'm Rather new to Atmel and C programming in general.
I've been trying to enable the interrupts on the Attiny817 dev board mentioned above, but I'm definitely having some issues. To better understand peripheral interrupts, I was attempting to use the onboard button (PC5) to control the onboard LED (PC0). I verified both pieces work by using the following statement:

```
#include <atmel_start.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int main(void){
    atmel_start_init();
    PORTC_set_pin_dir(PIN5_bp, false);
    PORTC_set_pin_dir(PIN0_bp,true);
    PORTC_set_pin_pull_mode(PIN5_bp,PORT_PULL_UP);
    while (1){
    if (!PORTC_get_pin_level(PIN5_bp)){
        PORTC_set_pin_level(PIN0_bp, true);
        }
    else{
        PORTC_set_pin_level(PIN0_bp, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well, so I attempted to implement the pin-change interrupt by writing the following:

```
#include <atmel_start.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int main(void){
    atmel_start_init();
    PORTC_set_pin_dir(PIN5_bp, false);
    PORTC_set_pin_dir(PIN0_bp,true);
    PORTC_set_pin_pull_mode(PIN5_bp,PORT_PULL_UP);
    PORTC_pin_set_isc(PIN5_bp, PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc); //detect rising and falling edges
    sei();

while (1) {
    }
}

ISR(PORTC_PORT_vect){
    PORTC_toggle_pin_level(PIN0_bp);
    PORTC.INTFLAGS |= PORT_INT5_bm;
}
```

My understanding from the datasheet was that all of PORTC shared an interrupt vector, and any interrupt on that Port would raise the respective flag within that vector. The data sheet also mentioned writing a '1' to the interrupt register to clear the interrupt, which is why I chose to write the ISR function this way. Additionally, the PORTC_pin_set_isc() function should perform the proper sense configuration in the PORTC register for the button on PC5.

What am I missing?
Any and All help appreciated.

A couple notes/updates:
a lot of these functions were pre-written by Atmel when I used their
Atmel | Start website to initialize drivers for me. (start.atmel.com/#)
Another quick update: I found example code on the AVRFreaks website, but when I use the code (exchanging PC3 for PC5), I run into the same issue where the interrupt is never called... (avrfreaks.net/comment/2435411#comment-2435411)

I also tried:
using the registers directly rather than the functions atmel created:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


int main(void)
{
    PORTC.DIRCLR = PIN5_bm;                     // Pin PC3 = input
    PORTC.DIRSET = PIN0_bm;                     // Pin PC0 = output
    
    PORTC.PIN5CTRL = PORT_PULLUPEN_bm;          // enables the internal pull-up resistor on PC3
    PORTC.PIN5CTRL |= PORT_ISC_FALLING_gc ;     // Sense falling edge on PC3. PORT_INT3_bp = 0x03
    
    // CPUINT.LVL0PRI = 0 << CPUINT_LVL0PRI_gp;     // Interrupt Level Priority: 0
    // CPUINT.LVL1VEC = 0x0A << CPUINT_LVL1VEC_gp;  // Interrupt Vector with High Priority: 0x08

    sei();                                      // Global interrupts enable

    while (1)
    {       
    }
}

ISR(PORTC_PORT_vect)
{
    PORTC.OUTTGL = PIN0_bm;                 // Toggle LED
    PORTC.INTFLAGS |= PORT_INT5_bm  ;       // Clear Interrupt
}
```

Comment: OT: Please [edit] your question to add new information. Down here in the comments they tend to get ignored. You might like to take the [tour] again. ;-)

Comment: What is PC5_bp. Because in some internet sources, they use PC5_bp, PC5_bm, and on others, the code `PORTC_pin_set_isc( 5, PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc);` is used. So either a bitmask or per port 0-based pin number.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. the bm(bit mask) is the hex value that represents the location in the register while bp is the position. So for PC5 the bm is 0x20, and the bp is 5. If you use Atmel's functions, like PORTC_pin_set_isc( 5, PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc); you use the bit postition, as shown in the second section of code, and the function handles the rest. If you are writing directly to the port register (like the 3rd section of code), you use the bit mask, which is why I'm using or-equals and not just equal, since I don't want to affect the rest of the register.

Comment: "PORTC.OUTTGL = PIN0_bm;    // Toggle LED" does not look like a _toggle_.